# RHEL 6.5 in AWS, yum : Cannot retrieve repository metadata because of 404 Not Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, yum

I have a RHEL 6.5 EC2 instance and yum is broken

yum clean all

```
 $ yum clean all
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, security
Cleaning repos: dag epel rhui-REGION-client-config-server-6 rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases-optional
              : rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rh-common rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rhscl webmin
Cleaning up Everything
```

yum clean metadata

```
 $ yum clean metadata
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, security
Cleaning repos: dag epel rhui-REGION-client-config-server-6 rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases-optional
              : rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rh-common rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rhscl webmin
0 metadata files removed
0 sqlite files removed
0 metadata files removed
```

After clean, try list update, but result 404 errors

```
 $ yum list update
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, security
dag                                                                                                                                    | 1.9 kB     00:00     
dag/primary_db                                                                                                                         | 2.7 MB     00:03     
epel/metalink                                                                                                                          | 5.2 kB     00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                   | 4.3 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                                                                                                        | 5.8 MB     00:00     
rhui-REGION-client-config-server-6                                                                                                     | 2.9 kB     00:00     
rhui-REGION-client-config-server-6/primary_db                                                                                          | 6.0 kB     00:00     
https://rhui2-cds02.ap-northeast-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/6/%24releasever/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
https://rhui2-cds01.ap-northeast-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/6/%24releasever/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases. Please verify its path and try again
```

I also tried the workaround mentioned in AWS forum, but failed to install the package
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=76738

```
 $ rpm -Uhv http://redhat-clientconfig-ap-northeast-1.s3.amazonaws.com/rh-amazon-rhui-client-2.2.16-1.el6.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://redhat-clientconfig-ap-northeast-1.s3.amazonaws.com/rh-amazon-rhui-client-2.2.16-1.el6.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/bash is needed by rh-amazon-rhui-client-2.2.16-1.el6.noarch
    /bin/sh is needed by rh-amazon-rhui-client-2.2.16-1.el6.noarch
    /usr/bin/python is needed by rh-amazon-rhui-client-2.2.16-1.el6.noarch
    /usr/bin/python2 is needed by rh-amazon-rhui-client-2.2.16-1.el6.noarch
    chkconfig is needed by rh-amazon-rhui-client-2.2.16-1.el6.noarch
    yum >= 3.2.22-20 is needed by rh-amazon-rhui-client-2.2.16-1.el6.noarch
    yum-rhn-plugin is needed by rh-amazon-rhui-client-2.2.16-1.el6.noarch
```

Can anyone provide some advice ?

Thanks

Comment: Start a new instance. This one has been pretty completely hosed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton , are you suspecting that yum setting may has been corrupted ?